# How to only show a loading bar on requests taking longer than n

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I've got a loading bar that is displayed on each HTTP request. This works perfectly for requests that take more than 300ms or so (such as API calls that fetch a lot of data), but looks silly when a request is short, the bar just flashes then vanishes and is rather distracting.

I'm trying to work out how I can hide the loading bar unless the time taken to return is longer than *n*ms.

To control the loading bar I have a simple method on `AppCompoent`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {

  loading: boolean = true;

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    router.events.subscribe((routerEvent: Event) => {
      this.checkRouterEvent(routerEvent);
    });
  }

  checkRouterEvent(routerEvent: Event): void {
    if (routerEvent instanceof NavigationStart) {

       // sleep here for n ms perhaps?

      this.loading = true;
    }

    if (routerEvent instanceof NavigationEnd ||
      routerEvent instanceof NavigationCancel ||
      routerEvent instanceof NavigationError) {
      this.loading = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Or is the already a standard pattern I've completely missed on how to handle this situation?

Comment: This is not connected with the request at all. It displays loader when navigating inside application from one route to another.

Comment: Okay that's cool and cheers for the clarification, doesn't' really help with the question though.

Comment: Link, which may help you https://medium.com/@zeljkoradic/loader-bar-on-every-http-request-in-angular-6-60d8572a21a9

Comment: I've implemented the link exactly as described, all its done is added a lot more lines of code, I'm still seeing the same behaviour as the much shorter and cleaner solution I originally had. The loading bar blinks for a flash when switching between pages which that make remote calls, despite those calls being 15ms or less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add a new variable to account for a "finished loading" state.

Here is a solution: add a `finishedLoading: boolean = true;` to your class. Then:

```
checkRouterEvent(routerEvent: Event): void {
  if (routerEvent instanceof NavigationStart) {
    this.finishedLoading = false;
    this.loading = false;
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (!this.finishedLoading) {
        this.loading = true;
      }
    } , 300);
  }

  if (routerEvent instanceof NavigationEnd ||
    routerEvent instanceof NavigationCancel ||
    routerEvent instanceof NavigationError) {
    this.finishedLoading = true;
    this.loading = false;
  }
}
```